# Adaptive card JSON is not rendering the Add-in UI in Windows Outlook look and feel

Tags: outlook, office365, outlook-addin, office-addins, adaptive-cards

I have created an Add-in for Outlook. I am using Adaptive cards to render the add-in UI. The UI is not rendering in Outlook look and feel, in other words the styling is not getting applied. Is there anything I need to do in my add-in for this to take effect?

I used the sample Adaptive card to create a HTML and JS based Outlook add-in which renders UI in the taskpane.

Comment: A sample markup would be helpful. It is hard to suggest anything without seeing the exact HTML markup with CSS styles.

Comment: Comments is the best place for the code samples. Try to edit your post and paste the markup.

Comment: As per the documentation --

Adaptive Cards are a platform-agnostic method of sharing and displaying blocks of information without the complexity of customizing CSS or HTML to render them. You author Adaptive Cards in JSON format, with integrations that cloud apps and services can openly exchange. When delivered to a specific host, such as Microsoft Teams, the JSON is transformed into native UI that automatically adapts to its host

I am not using any CSS and was hoping AC will take care of it. What am I doing wrong? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Adaptive cards received as [actionable messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/send-via-email) in Outlook are rendered and styled to match the host, but this is separate functionality from Outlook add-ins.  My guess is for an add-in you are on your own and will need to apply the Outlook styling, e.g., using the [CSS from the Adaptive Card designer tool](https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/blob/main/source/nodejs/adaptivecards-designer/src/containers/outlook/outlook-container.css).  This is not documented as far as I know, so these styles may be out of date.